# How to check 100 items efficiently?

Tags: java

I am making a game in Java. I want to be able to check whether a level has been previously visited.
I came up with this:

```java
public class LevelTracker {

  boolean depth1visited = false;
  boolean depth2visited = false;
  // ..
  boolean depth100visited = false;


  private boolean LevelTracking() {
    if (Dungeon.depth == 1) {
      depth1visited = true;
    }
    if (Dungeon.depth == 2) {
      depth2visited = true;
    }
    // ..
    if (Dungeon.depth == 100) {
      depth100visited = true;
    }
  }
}
```

In my situation, each depth must be checked independently since any level might be accessed from any other level. So this:

```java
if (depth > deepestdepth) {
  deepestdepth = depth;
}
```

won't work in my situation. Unless I'm wrong, which is possible. I am, as you can probably tell, a novice at this.

What is a better way to do this? Could a for loop be used in this situation?

Comment: Have you learned about arrays?

Comment: Since I see they're just depth[somenumber]visited then a boolean depthvisited[] = {} should work for this, then just loop through it.

Comment: build an array and loop through the array much simpler

Comment: I wasn't sure at all if I could actually use arrays for this. They are still new and scary to me. But if it'll work here then I will definitely have a good look at how I can use them.

Answer (score 1):

Use arrays, which can be addressed by index.  This can replace all your `if`s and your 100 separate variables.

```
boolean[] depthVisited = new boolean[100];  // default values: false
```

Then you can access the array by calculating an index.

```
depthVisited[Dungeon.depth - 1] = true;  // 0-based index
```

No `for` loop is necessary.

Comment: Ok, cool. I really wasn't sure if I could even apply an array to this kind of problem. I thought (why, I don't know) that I couldn't apply it to this particular problem.